# Нарисовать кнопку на svg

Tags: svg

Подскажите как нарисовать вот такую кнопку на svg[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вроде бы так ...рисовал без редактора SVG

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 1 270 75" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="270">
  <path d="M3,36 C3,36 2,11 30,7 L246,6 C246,6 278,13 264,51 L268,75 217,65 26,65 C26,65 4,62 3,36" 
        fill="#ffd4d5"/>
</svg>
```

С редактора

```html
<svg viewBox="5 269 73.808495 18.61533" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <path d="m 13.356167,268.90458 57.92485,0.0945 c 4.8978,-0.0403 7.47846,6.53474 4.34673,12.37872 l 0.37798,6.14211 -5.85864,-2.55134 -57.735861,-0.0945 c -9.4712613,0.032 -9.4712613,-15.87056 0.944941,-15.96949 z" fill="#ffd4d5"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а можно покрасивее?

Comment: Что за редактор?

Comment: @MaximLensky спасибо, класс

Comment: @MaximLensky, а что за редактор?

Comment: @MaximLensky спасибо

Answer (score 3):

```css
g {
  fill: #fdd;
  transition: 500ms;
}
g:hover {
  fill: wheat;
}
text {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<svg>
 <defs>
    <filter id="shadow" x=-50% y=-50% width=200% height=200%>
       <feDropShadow dx="5" dy="5" stdDeviation="5" 
                     flood-color="#333" flood-opacity=".1" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  
  <g>
    <rect filter="url(#shadow)"  
          x="10" y="10" width="270" height="70" rx="25" />
    <polygon points="270 60  250 80  285 95" />   
  </g>
  <text x="140" y="50" text-anchor="middle">example text</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: СПАСИБО, а как текст вставить по центру?

Comment: @spoon100500 добавил текст, только не снимайте галочку с ответа Максима, раз поставили её уже =)

Comment: Я так же сделал, спасибо.

Comment: А как можно объеденить rect и polygon что бы задать один fill? Нужно что бы при наведении цвет svg менялся.

Comment: @spoon100500 готово

Comment: Только что сделал))) Спасибо

Comment: @spoon100500 если мой ответ сложнее - отметь ответ Stranger in the Q  решением

Comment: @MaximLensky ну не надо таких жертв :D

Comment: @StrangerintheQ он всё равно твой код использует https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1109795/308951

Comment: @MaximLensky ну и ладно, все равно я думаю переставлять галку - не правильно